# Simple and quick way to produce test database from production database?

Tags: database, testing, sql-server-2012

Do we have any tool  that can reduce data in the database, that means to create a test database?
It could be a wizard with functionality:
1) choose tables that you want to "preserve" (like classificators)
2) choose table that you want to truncate and point the number of records that you want to left, then all "related" tables will be truncated by analyzing fk references.
3) repeat 2 by choosing another table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this looks like what you look for [Jailer](http://jailer.sourceforge.net/exporting-data.htm) It exports consistent, referentially intact row-sets from relational databases.